# Crystal Reports 4.6 and the infamous Automation Error -2147417848 The object invoked has disconnected from its clients

Tags: crystal-reports, vb6

I am updating a DAO application from 16 bit VB3 to 32 bit VB6 (yes it is 2014, don't ask..)
Using VB6 SP6 + Crystal Reports package that comes with VB6 (version 4.6).

The application has multiple forms that produce reports. I had a Crystal Reports control on every form that produced reports.

In my dev machine - which has all the correct OCX and DLLs for CryRpt - reports were working sometimes but I was getting the mentioned error under this scenario:

- Open Form 1 and Print something
- Open Form 2 and print something
- Close Form 2
- Go back to Form 1 and when you try to print, you get the Object has Disconnected from its clients
- If you re open Form 2 (or another form with a Crystal Reports control on it), Form 1 *may* start printing again while the new form is open
- Amidst all this open and close, the whole thing eventually crashes with a nasty windows error message (including the VB IDE).

All the best,
Pedro

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found a work around, which I'd like to share in case anyone else runs into this.

As it seems, you *can't* have multiple forms with the Crystal Reports 4.6 OCX on them. Use only 1 OCX instance per application.
CR 4.6 does not seem to handle well the loading and unloading of the OCX and sharing the associated DLLs behind the scenes when opening and closing multiple forms that have the CR's OCX on them.

The work around I found was to create one single form that has one Crystal Reports OCX on it.
This form is always loaded but hidden; it is used/called by all the forms in the app whenever I need to render the reports.
In short:

- Crate Form "prntHndlr" (or use any name you want) and place the Crystal Reports OCX on it.
- Load this form (but leave it hidden) on application start
- you need to create 1 public method (say "MyPrintReport") in frmPrntHndlr to receive the parameters and print the reports (receives RPT file path, DB path, sort order, selectionformula, etc.)

Whenever I need to print, I call prntHndlr.MyPrintReport(....).
The function takes the arguments, assigns them to the OCX and finally "Shows" the report.

The function can be recalled as many times as you need.

When the application closes, the form needs to be unloaded by the last form. (other wise it won't actually close and stay in process manager).

Works like a charm!

It took me hours to track this down (no help from Google) so I thought it'd be useful to share this with the community.

Once again, if you know of any workaround or better way to handle this, please let me know

All the best,
Pedro

Comment: Many VB things have disappeared from the internet over the last 14 years (SP6 was released). I have MSDN Library CD from 1998 to 2001 and it filled with stuff MS has removed from the web site.